# Options Menu Available In All Activities

Tags: java, android, menu, kotlin, settings

I'm making an Android application and currently in my MainActivity I have an onCreate and listeners for an option menu. I want this menu available in all my activities and while I want to know if there's a better way to do that than copying the onCreate into each one. My code for the menu is below.

```
// onCreateOptionsMenu()
// Create options menu
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
    return true
}

// onOptionsItemSelected()
// "On click listener" for options menu
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId

    when(id) {
        R.id.action_settings -> { // Selected settings
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.action_about_us -> { // About us selected
            // Go to About activity
        }
        R.id.action_rate_us -> { // Rate us selected
            // Go to Google Play store
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a abstract class parent activity with same code of yours above then extend the activity you want to inherit the property/method of your parent activity.